# Using same model from store in a component used in all routes in Ember 2.8.0

Tags: json, ember.js

My use case: application has a header that displays current user's name. This header is the same on all pages.

User data is loaded from JSON API into the Store when user logs in.

Now, how am I supposed to access this data from Store to use it on every page?

---

1. One option is to pass it from routes:

`{{app-header user=model}}`

But then I would have to use the same model in all the routes and also would be unable to use any other? How can a (supposedly reusable) component expect from me to adjust every route to its data structure?

---

2. The other option is that component always loads data from Store on its own, but this seems strongly unrecommended and actually very hard to do for me without any proper guide. I managed to discover service injection method (`store: Ember.inject.service()` in the component) but still can't get the component to properly display data from store in the template.

When I use:

```
name: () => {
    return this.store.peekRecord('user', 1).get('name');
  }
```

then `{{name}}` in template renders function definition, not what it returns.

When I use:

```
 name: Ember.computed(() => {
    return this.store.peekRecord('user', 1).get('name');    
  })
```

then `{{name}}` renders: `<!---->`

---

Could you please explain what is a good way to do this? Is there some "master model" defined in `application.js` besides models from routes? Should I really pass the same data to component in every route? Any information or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a service ([guide here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/applications/services/)).

```
// app/services/store.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Store.extend({});

// app/services/user-service.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  user: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('user', ':id');
  })
});
```

Then, in all your other components, controllers, and routes, you can access the service.

```
// Inside a controller
export default Ember.controller.extend({
  userService: Ember.inject.service(),

  firstName: Ember.computed.alias('userService.user.firstName')
});
```

The first name, or even the user object itself is now available in you template.

```
{{userService.user.firstName}}
OR
{{firstName}}
```

Comment: Well, it seems I can't set the property in Service properly from store - either when it is a function or with simple syntax you suggested.

Comment: In order to set the property, you will need to wait for the promise from the store to resolve. something like. `this.store.findRecord('user', ':id').then(user => this.set('userService.user', user))`

Comment: Also to get `store` inside your service you may need to create another service called store like in this example from [ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html)

Comment: I used `Ember.RSVP.hash`, is that not enough?

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote here and I have an issue - I can't display data loaded in my computed property... even though my other computed properties using this computed property can. This is very weird. Shall I edit my question? Are you sure your syntax should work?

Comment: I use `findRecord` so it's async and more complicated.

Comment: I updated my answer to be a bit more specific and I'm pretty sure it would work now. Obviously this is provided your models and store are all set up correctly but that is a bit out of the scope of this question.

Comment: It turned out my API mock was not set up correctly and once I fixed that it all worked fine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First approach, (**Keeping it in Application Route**)

1.Define it in application route model hook - refer multiple modelsin single route.(https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_multiple-models)
2.If its required in another route, then you can access already resolved model of the parent route through `modelFor` method.(http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor)

Second Approach, (**Service**)

Like @devman answer, you can load it in `service` and inject and get it wherever you require.

```
 userService:Ember.inject.service();
 name: Ember.computed.alias('userService.name')
```

Comment: I already implemented the first one and it seems to work. So it's correct to reference the entire application "global" model in route models and pass to component like `{{model.global.user}}`?

Comment: Or probably I will need a service for authentication anyway, so I'll go try that approach as well.